# How to execute JavaScript code in EJS template?

Tags: javascript, templates, ejs

If possible I want to change only the `ejs` file that looks like:

```
...
<?= comment.description -?>
...
```

`comment.description` contains something like this:

```
foo
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Is it possible to execute JavaScript code inside of template *before* using `comment.description`?

I only want to delete the first line of `comment.description`:

```
comment.description = comment.description.split("\n").slice(1).join("\n");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` means that what's inside is going to be visible in html. To make a variable or compute JS you don't need `=`.

E.g.:

```
<? comment.description = comment.description.split("\n").slice(1).join("\n"); -?>  
<?= comment.description -?>
```